# Vim :cnext :cprev create new tabs, how to make the use the same tab?

Tags: vim

I am using Ag and it was fine moving through the results with `:cn` and `:cp`. But now something has changed and it create new tabs for files as soon as I switch to a new file.

I use `unimpaired-vim` and the new tab is open both with `[q` `]q` and `:cn` `:cp`. Don't see any additional settings in my `.vimrc` in regards to that..

Comment: The quickfix window can't be "autoclosed"; it is closed only if *you* or some script close it. Can you share your vimrc?

Comment: Sure thing, please feel free to advise if you think there is anything wrong with it: https://github.com/firedev/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: You could try narrowing down whether a plugin or vimrc change is causing the problem, [using `git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search) on the Git repository with your `vimrc`. Check out the commit when you first added [ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim), and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, bisect with the commit as “good”, and with the latest commit as “bad”. Test each time what `:Ag` and then `:cn` does. That will locate the commit that changed the behavior, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

After using Rory advice and git bisecting vimrc I finally found what was causing it:

```
set switchbuf= ..., newtab
```

After removing newtab everyting went back to normal.